# Hibernate перезаписывает данные

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Доброго дня, товарищи.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: сконфигурировал Hibernate, начал записывать сущности, всё хорошо, но после перезапуска приложения таблица очищается и данные записываются заново. Как сделать, чтобы при перезапуске данные дополнялись, а не перезаписывались?
UPD: выкладываю листинг конфигурации

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="model.PostEntity"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Узнал, что hbm2ddl.auto со значением create виновен в вопросе, но допустим при первом запуске таблицы вообще нет, а при повторном нужно проверять её существование.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос конфиг hibernate и код метода для записи в БД

Comment: Вопрос не в записи а в самом запуске хибера. Он чистит таблицу и заново заливает в неё данные.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto может принимать такие значения:

1. **validate**: проверяет схему но не вносит изменения.
2. **update**: обновляет схему
3. **create**: создаёт схему удаляя старую
4. **create-drop**: удаляет схему после окончания сессии.

вам нужно заменить **create** на **update**

Answer (score 3):

Это происходит из-за:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

> **validate**: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
>   **update**: update the schema.
>   **create**: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
>   **create-drop**: drop the schema at the end of the session.

Comment: это написано в вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле я смотрел в правильную сторону, сюда нужно указать update и даже если таблицы нет, он её создаст и при каждом перезапуске будет дополнять.

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```